# Magento hostname validation errors

Tags: email, magento, zend-framework

When i tried to register with an email on magento store that I am developing I came across with errors that i havent seen before
 that says:

```
"Email" is not a valid hostname

does not appear to be a valid local network name

appears to be a DNS hostname but cannot match TLD against known list magento
```

When I did my research I foundout that these errors comes are caused by the Zend hostname validation.

Is it possible to resolve these or there's no solution at all

Comment: Was the email address you were trying to register with valid?

Comment: the domain name of the email doesn't show up when i try to hit onthe browser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I encountered same error :

```
"Email" is not a valid hostname.
'example.example' appears to be a DNS hostname but cannot match TLD against known list
'example.example' appears to be a local network name but local network names are not allowed
```

From Magento 1, it appears that Zend is using a hardcoded list of Tlds :

```
     /**
     * Array of valid top-level-domains
     *
     * @see ftp://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt  List of all TLDs by domain
     * @see http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/ Official list of supported TLDs
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_validTlds = array(
        'ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'aero', 'af', 'ag', 'ai', 'al', 'am', 'an', 'ao', 'aq', 'ar', 'arpa',
        [...]
        'ye', 'yt', 'yu', 'za', 'zm', 'zw'
    );
```

So, there are some options :

- **Option 1** : updating this list from [zend github](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/136735e776f520b081cd374012852cb88cef9a88/library/Zend/Validate/Hostname.php#L119)
- **Option 2** : removing the domain validation
- **Option 3** : From @[Aleksey Razbakov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/517595/aleksey-razbakov) comment, we can only check the MX record : https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.email_address.checkacceptance

---

For **Option 2** we can perform a safe-upgrade of the following file, or see *option 3* to add `$validator->getHostnameValidator()->setValidateTld(false);`, copying it from :

`/lib/Zend/Validate/Hostname.php`

to :

`/app/code/local/Zend/Validate/Hostname.php`

Then look for this block of code, and just comment the three lines :

```
if (!in_array($this->_tld, $this->_validTlds)) {
  // $this->_error(self::UNKNOWN_TLD);
  // $status = false;
  // break;
}
```

---

For **Option 3** we can perform a safe-upgrade of the following file, copying it from :

`app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data/Abstract.php`

to :

`/app/code/local/Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data/Abstract.php`

Then replace this code :

```
$validator = new Zend_Validate_EmailAddress();
```

by :

```
// 1. we check mx record
$validator = new Zend_Validate_EmailAddress(
    array(
      'allow' => Zend_Validate_Hostname::ALLOW_DNS,
      'mx'    => true
    )
);
// 2. we remove TLD validation :
$validator->getHostnameValidator()->setValidateTld(false);
```

Do not forget to look for every call of the `Zend_Validate_EmailAddress` class that can be used in community or custom extensions (e.g : onestepcheckout).

Answer (score 0):

There are new generic Top Level Domain extension (gTLDs). These are 
going to cause issues with Zend Validator.

The best fix is to disable hostname validation in Magento and 
leave it up to the end user to correctly enter a domain name:

find `Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute_Data_Abstract` and

change

```
$validator = new Zend_Validate_EmailAddress();
```

to

```
$validator = new Zend_Validate_EmailAddress(array('domain'=>false));
```

Or you can simply [install patch via composer](https://github.com/kirchbergerknorr/magento-disable-email-hostname-validation/).

Comment: I think calling this a "patch" is extremely misleading. For me, and the majority a patch is an official code update from Magento. The code you mention is not official.

Comment: Didn't I answer the question?

It is not official patch. But it is a patch. It would be nice to do it as a diff but it is not possible with composer. 

P.S. Read wiki: A patch is a piece of software designed to update a computer program or its supporting data, to fix or improve it. This includes fixing security vulnerabilities and other bugs, with such patches usually called bugfixes or bug fixes, and improving the usability or performance.

Comment: You advocate removing the entire functionality of the check. In my mind this is not a "patch".

Comment: Read my answer. There are new generic Top Level Domain extension (gTLDs). Zend_Validate_EmailAddress is not up-to-date anymore to check domain addresses. Now it can be anything.

Comment: What can be useful here is checking if the hostname actually accepts email - http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.email_address.checkacceptance

Comment: How to fix in Magento 2?

Comment: @AnkitShah This has been fixed in M2 - see https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4547.

Comment: Mind that this solution is not enough. Customer account creation still fails. To fix this, you have to update `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::validate` as well.